# Heap updating order

Tags: sorting, heap, heapsort

here's a working code for heapsort algorithm, my question is if in heap creation I swap the condition in the code with

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i  < dim/2-1; i ++)
```

that I think it's the for cycle but in reverse order and I think that the process of updating the heap is quite the same (in my head we go trough updating the heap condition for every index from 0 to the end of the array),why the algorithm won't work anymore? It's wrong written the other condition or simply the algorithm is designed to work decreasing the index i? Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Scambia( int *px, int *py);

void  Aggiornaheap( int *pa, int i, int j);

int main(void)
{
    int a[256];
    int n;
    int dim = 0;
    
    // Lettura dell’input da tastiera
    while (scanf("%d\n", &n) == 1)
    {
        a[dim] = n;
        dim++;
    }

    // heap creation
    for ( int i = dim/2-1 ; i  >= 0; i --)
    {
    Aggiornaheap(a, i, dim);
    }

    //Heapsort
    for ( int i = dim-1; i  >= 0; i --)
    {
    Scambia(&a[0], &a[i]);
    Aggiornaheap(a, 0, i-1);
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");

return 0;
}

void Scambia( int *px, int *py)
{
    int temp;

    temp = *px;
    *px = *py;
    *py = temp;

}

void  Aggiornaheap( int *pa, int i, int j)
{
    int k;
    if ( 2*i == j )
    {
        if ( pa[i] < pa[j])
        Scambia(&pa[i], &pa[j]);
    }

    if ( 2*i < j )
    {
        if ( pa[2*i] > pa[2*i+1] )
            k = 2*i;
        else k = 2*i+1;
    
        if ( pa[i] < pa[k])
        {
            Scambia(&pa[i], &pa[k]);
            Aggiornaheap(pa, k, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary that the nodes are visited in reverse order. The algorithm will not do its job correctly if you change that order.

Take for instance this input tree that needs to be heapified into a min-heap: [2,4,3,1], which can be visualised as follows:

```
            2
           / \
          4   3
         /
        1
```

Then note how it will be impossible for the 1 value to bubble to the top, when you alter the `for` loop to go forward. Let's just try this. When `i==0` nothing is swapped, because 2 is less than its children. When `i==1` then 4 will be swapped with 1, and then the loop has finished. Clearly, this has not created a valid heap.

If however we start with `i==1`, which triggers the swap of 1 with 4, and only *then* have `i==0`, then we will again swap 1 to move up:

```
            1
           / \
          2   3
         /
        4
```

One comment about your code. It looks like you work with zero-indexed arrays, with the root element at 0, but in that case the children are at `i*2+1` and `i*2+2`, not one less like we see in your code.

Comment: Thank you I understand why it isn't working with the for condition switched, now with your observation on the index I'm trying to understand if it's a big issue, because I've run a couple of examples and it seems to work fine, do you think it's worth changing the index or make the array start from 1?

Comment: As the index formula is now, it will fail in some situations. It is just not correct, and so it is a big issue. Yes, correct the formula. Starting from 1 is an alternative, but it just wastes the entry at index 0, so I would correct the formula. See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) which assumes index starting at 1. But I would only do that if the programming language organizes arrays like that (starting with index 1). For zero-based indexing I would change the formula.

Comment: One last question: starting at zero and not changing the formula leads to a creation of a tree that has only one root's son and then is a binary tree for every other node, am I right? Isn't still a heap? Thank you

Comment: Yes, that is true. But the definition of a binary heap is that it is a *complete* binary tree.

Comment: So in term of definition it's clearly another object, and so it can not be a binary heap. In term of algorithmic operation I think still works fine because, the root in a binary tree that represent a binary heap is the max element, so the "zero" element will be compared to the root, switched in case is less than and then as a chain reaction if needed will be modified the entire tree below. It's clearly nothing formal... What do you think about that?

Comment: But binary heaps were invented to improve performance. Now you will have on average a tree that has one more level than a binary heap would have. So also from a performance point of view, you should just stick to the data structure as it was intended.

Comment: Oh yes from a performance point of view it's a downgrade, I didn't think about it. I'll change the formula, but what I'm saying is that (if I understood how heap and heap sort  work) the code do its job , It just performs worse due to this unnecessary upper level.

Comment: In your second `if` block, check what happens when `i` is 0: `pa[2*i] > pa[2*i+1]`. If that condition is true, then a swap needs to happen, but you then set `k` to be equal to the root, so no swap will happen, and the root will remain greater than its only child, which is wrong.